# Reactjs ES6 Access function outside of class

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class "MessageDisplay" of which I want to call the function sendMassageToServer from the outside. I´ve built a helper function to call from another file. But how do you export functions that are inside classes?

These data are just examples.

main.js

```
export function sendSpeechToServer(query){
  MessageDisplay.sendMessageToServer(query);
}

class MessageDisplay extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {message : []};
    }
    (export const??) sendMessageToServer(searchQuery) {
     ...code
    }
}
```

We are accesing the sendSpeechToServer() function from another file. Unortunately I am not even able to reach sendMessageToServer() from inside sendSpeechToServer().

Any help surely is appreciated. :)

EDIT:
The answer is found. For any other people:

```
export function sendSpeechToServer(query){
  let test = new MessageDisplay();
  test.sendMessageToServer(query);
}
```

Comment: Then you may delete the post or answer your own question if you think the post is not duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Better way to separate component(MessageDisplay) and sendMessageToServer. 
Then you can import sendMessageToServer awry where. You can inject `sendMessageToServer` like a props:

```js
// main.js
import { sendMessageToServer } from './api';

<MessageDisplay sendMessage={sendMessageToServer} />

// MessageDisplay.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MessageDisplay extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    sendMessage: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.sendMessage();
  };

  render() {
    return (<button onClick={this.handleClick}>Send to</button>)
  }
}

export default MessageDisplay;
```

It useful for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating a component manually for general purposes like `let test = new MessageDisplay()` is an antipattern, this indicates that a class is misused.

React component classes are primarily intended to make lifecycle hooks available and maintain `state`. They can sparsely benefit from inheritance (besides the relationship with `React.Component`) and other OOP traits.

The fact that it's possible to use component method as `new MessageDisplay().sendMessageToServer(query)` means that it was a mistake to make it component method in the first place. Classes aren't supposed to be glorified namespaces; ES modules play the role of namespaces in modern JavaScript.

A proper way is to extract the method and use it in both places as regular helper function. Functional approach is considered idiomatic in React.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function sendSpeechToServer(query){
  let test = new MessageDisplay();
  test.sendMessageToServer(query);
}
```

it is bad, because you should not, create new react.component instance with new keyword,
better use static function like this

```
static sendMessageToServer(searchQuery) {
     ...code
    }
```

and then

```
export function sendSpeechToServer(query){
  MessageDisplay.sendMessageToServer(query);
}
```